# Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './crypto_auth' sodium-universal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, libsodium

I am getting the following error when attempting to browserify a node project (https://github.com/datproject/sdk) and am getting the following error.

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './crypto_auth' from 'C:\myPath\node_modules\sodium-universal\index.js'
    required by C:\myPath\node_modules\sodium-universal\index.js
    at C:\myPath\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:137:35
    at load (C:\myPath\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:156:43)
    at onex (C:\myPath\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:181:17)
    at C:\myPath\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:15:69
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Usually I'd `npm install` the missing module. However, this doesn't work in this case. Also I can find no mention of `crypt_auth` anywhere in the project (the referenced`index.js` has a single line `module.exports = require('sodium-native')`)

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Paul90's comment [here](https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-universal/issues/6#issuecomment-753595459), I solved like this:

1. cd into the `yourPath/node_modules/sodium-universal/build-scripts` dir
2. run `node generate.js`
3. go back to the `sdk` dir and run `npm run build`